# Strange Arrow in Visual Studio Gutter Window

Tags: visual-studio-2012

What does the following **arrow icon** mean in the Visual Studio 2012 *gutter window*?  I've never seen it before.

This particular line of code has nothing special about it, nor do I recall doing anything to this line that would cause an arrow to appear.  It's definately attached to this line of code.  Moving the line of code down causes the arrow to follow.

I have no add-ons installed in Visual Studio.

[image: Arrow in gutter window]

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It marks a Task List shortcut.  You add them with Edit > Bookmarks > Add Task List Shortcut, [Ctrl+E,T] keystroke.  That adds an entry to the task list, use View > Task List to display it.  Select "Shortcuts" in the combobox.  You'll see a list of all the shortcuts you added.  Double-click an entry to jump to the line.

Remove it again with Edit > Bookmarks > Remove Task List Shortcut, [Ctrl+E,T] again.

---

**NOTE:** In visual studio 2015 and above, its [Ctrl+K,Ctrl+H]

Comment: BTW, You can also add tasks to the task list directly from code. Any line which begins with `// TODO` will be added to the task list automatically. This is a much more intuitive way to add tasks IMHO. Depending on the file type, this may not be possible though so both ways to add a task are good to know.

Comment: In VS2015 it is Ctrl+K,H

Comment: In VS2017 you can use both keyboard shortcuts (Ctrl+K,H or Ctrl+E,T). Seems the latter conflicts with Test Explorer