# Get rid of "diagonal arrow" in Visual Studio 2015 editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

What is the white diagonal arrow (red-circled on the picture below) placed in usually a column for breakpoint?

What is it and how to get rid of it?

I think I accidentally pressed a key combination but don't remember what it is.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15120139/strange-arrow-in-visual-studio-gutter-window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [Task List short-cut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txtwdysk.aspx).

These can be edited through the **Edit > Book Marks > Add/Remove Task List Shortcut** menu item within Visual Studio. You should be able to manually remove them via the Menu option or by simply using the `CTRL+K,H` short-cut.

If you want to actually take advantage of them, you can view all of your current Tasks via **View > Task List** or by using the `CTRL+W,T` short-cut.

Answer (score 2):

That's `Task List ShortCut` to get rid of it try `Edit -> BookMark -> Remove TaskList ShortCut`. See [How to: Use Task List Shortcuts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/k4efffwe(v=vs.90).aspx)